# Understanding jQuery API Documentation Syntax

Tags: jquery

From http://api.jquery.com/on/:

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )
```

I know this might sound a little stupid, but could anyone explain the syntax here?

What does the [] mean? I would think it means that you could add several options (selectors/data) but as you can also add several events, why does `events` not have square brackets?

Also here's an example .on():

```
    $(document).on("click", ".item", function() {
alert("hi");
});
```

Where does the `data` written in the method syntax come into play here?

Comment: I believe they are optional, events is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square brackets indicate that an argument is optional. For the `.on()` method, both `selector` and `data` are optional, but `events` and `handler` are required.

For example:

```
$(something).on("click", function () {});
//                 ^ events    ^ handler

$(something).on("click", ".child", function () {});
//                ^ events   ^ selector   ^ handler

$(something).on(function () {}); // Won't work, missing events argument
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` indicate those parameters are optional. You can have zero or one `selector`s and `data`.

The example call omits the `data` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets indicate that the parameter is optional. So you can optionally provide a selector (for event delegation) or data (for use inside the event handler function), but you don't have to.

With regard to your specific example, there isn't any value being passed to `data` (because you don't have to do so). In the code for the jQuery `on` function it determines which parameter the value is actually for based on the type of the value.